# Wordpress - How can i get the current Author data with another Function

Tags: php, wordpress, user-data, author

I wondering of how can i override the $curauth to some function to get the current author data, I searched a lot and tested more and more functions without any success.

I used this line into author.php for sure to get the author by slug or name, So how can i get the same author data with another php function?

```
<?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>
```

to be more clear..As we know when we need to get some of user meta we get it like so.

```
$following = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);
```

Now if i have an function and i need to get the same user meta, What should i do.

NOTE: I need to get the user meta to be public for all users not only for current user!

e.g:

```
function pwuf_following_users () {

    $curauth = (...?...);

    $following = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_pwuf_following', true);

    if ( empty($following)) {

        //do something

    } else {

        //Another awesome something

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get all users data using below code:

```
$users_list = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'author', 'subscriber' ] ] );
foreach ( $users_list as $user ) {
    $userdata = get_user_meta($user->ID);
    if($userdata != "")
    {
       //Do something
       print_r($userdata); // Here you will get data of specific user by its Id
    }
    else
    {
       //Another awesome something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @raju for your answer, but what if i need the only users inside the user meta `_pwuf_following` ?

Comment: use this code : get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_pwuf_following', true );

Comment: Hello I tried what you said, but not working, Can you please check this question about what i really need to do. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606104/wordpress-users-list-with-ajax-pagination-within-author-profile)